# Telephone mask not working with maskedinput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maskedinput

I am not getting the mask to show up when I am typing a number like it shows on their demo.
I am using `gem 'maskedinput-rails'`.

My code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <%= f.telephone_field :phone, class: 'form-control', value: number_to_phone(@appointment.phone, area_code: true) %>
  </div>
  <script> 
    jQuery(function($){
    $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
  </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is your selector correct? Does `$('#phone')` give you the phone field?

Comment: My understanding is $('#phone") relates to my variable f.telephone_field :phone, which relates to @appointment.phone.

Comment: It should be working like the Demo link at http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: When I use plain old <input type="text" id="phone" /> it works great.  But using   <%= f.telephone_field :phone, class: 'form-control', value: number_to_phone(@appointment.phone, area_code: true) %> it does not work.

Comment: Not even  <%= f.text_field :phone %> will work but <input type="text" id="phone" /> does which is supposed to be the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vee points out, the problem is with your selector. Once you have loaded your page in the browser, you can simply check the source to see what the ID of the text field is. That said, if you did not change [FormBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) configuration, it should be something like `#model_attribute`, so in your case `#appointment_phone`. So:

```
<script> 
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#appointment_phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You mentioned FormBuilder configuration.  I am a newbie to Rails so I am not sure what you are talking about. Are you talking about _form.html.erb? Where do I make a change with #appointment_phone?

Comment: I have edited my answer, and added a link to the FormBuilder doc.

Comment: Wow!  It works but I do not understand why that is the fix.  In all the examples I have looked at that surely is not clear at all.  Thanks for making my night TWICE!